# Git - Updating files of a repository with files from another

Tags: git, github

I have two repositories

```
https://github.com/Username/repoJohn.git 
https://github.com/Username/repoMary.git
```

Both repositories contain files:

```
dir1/file1.txt
dir2/file2.txt
```

The difference:

- the files of the first repository have been edited by John,
- the files from the second repository have been edited by Mary.

Nevertheless, we consider the files of Mary to be more up-to-date (for instance, they were built using files from John, but unfortunately the copy was done using a USB instead of creating a clone from Johns's repository). So at this point, repoMary has no information about the fact that files originated from repoJohn.

Now I want to create a third repository repoBoth where the history of each
file contains both John and Mary.

How do we do this in GitHub?

Comment: Set up different remotes to the third one and push and merge as needed

Comment: I'd create a new repository, add both as remotes (git remote add) and then pull from both repositories respectively merge them into the new one. Just my limited view, maybe there are better options.